# How to melt groups of columns along with adding columns specifying the column name where the values come from?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to be able to convert a wide form dataframe to long form, but while doing that I also want to add columns that specify the column names where the values actually come from. Here is what I mean -

**Original dataframe**

```py
pd.DataFrame({'A_1_H': list('abc'), 'B_1_H': list('123'), 'C_1_H': list('mno'), 'X_1_L': [9,8,7], 'Y_1_L':list('pqr'), 'Z_1_L':[1,2,3]})
```

```
    A_1_H   B_1_H   C_1_H   X_1_L   Y_1_L   Z_1_L
0    a       1       m       9       p       1
1    b       2       n       8       q       2
2    c       3       o       7       r       3
```

**What I want** -

```
    Col1    Key1    Col2    Key2
0    a      A_1_H    9      X_1_L 
1    b      A_1_H    8      X_1_L 
2    c      A_1_H    7      X_1_L 
3    1      B_1_H    p      Y_1_L 
4    2      B_1_H    q      Y_1_L 
5    3      B_1_H    r      Y_1_L 
6    m      C_1_H    1      Z_1_L 
7    n      C_1_H    2      Z_1_L 
8    o      C_1_H    3      Z_1_L
```

I am grouping the `_1_H` suffixed columns into one column `Col1` and the corresponding column names in `Key1` and similarly with the suffix `_1_L` into `Col2` with its keys in `Key2`.

Is there a way to do it effectively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) twice and `concat` both, use [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to select the columns _H and _L separately.

```
df_ = pd.concat([pd.melt(df.filter(regex='_H'), var_name='Key1', value_name='Col1'), 
                 pd.melt(df.filter(regex='_L'), var_name='Key2', value_name='Col2')],
                axis=1)
                 
print (df_)
    Key1 Col1   Key2 Col2
0  A_1_H    a  X_1_L    9
1  A_1_H    b  X_1_L    8
2  A_1_H    c  X_1_L    7
3  B_1_H    1  Y_1_L    p
4  B_1_H    2  Y_1_L    q
5  B_1_H    3  Y_1_L    r
6  C_1_H    m  Z_1_L    1
7  C_1_H    n  Z_1_L    2
8  C_1_H    o  Z_1_L    3
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), by passing a list of regular expressions:

```py
import pandas as pd
import janitor

( df
.pivot_longer(
    index = None, 
    names_to = ('Key1', 'Key2'), 
    values_to = ('Col1', 'Col2'), 
    names_pattern = ['A|B|C', 'X|Y|Z'])
)

    Key1 Col1   Key2 Col2
0  A_1_H    a  X_1_L    9
1  A_1_H    b  X_1_L    8
2  A_1_H    c  X_1_L    7
3  B_1_H    1  Y_1_L    p
4  B_1_H    2  Y_1_L    q
5  B_1_H    3  Y_1_L    r
6  C_1_H    m  Z_1_L    1
7  C_1_H    n  Z_1_L    2
8  C_1_H    o  Z_1_L    3
```